# How can my Heroku Flask web application support N users concurrently downloading an image file?

Tags: flask, heroku, concurrency

I am working on a Flask web application using Heroku. As part of the application, users can request to download an image from the server. That calls a function which has to then retrieve multiple images from my cloud storage (about 500 KB in total), apply some formatting, and return a single image (about 60 KB). It looks something like this:

```
@app.route('/download_image', methods=['POST'])
def download_image():
    # Retrieve about 500 KB of images from cloud storage
    base_images = retrieve_base_images(request.form)
    
    # Apply image formatting into a single image
    formatted_image = format_images(base_images)

    # Return image of about 60 KB for download
    formatted_image_file = io.BytesIO()
    formatted_image.save(formatted_image_file, format='JPEG')
    formatted_image_data = formatted_image_file.getvalue()
    return Response(formatted_image_data,
                    mimetype='image/jpeg',
                    headers={'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename=download.jpg'})
```

My Procfile is

```
web: gunicorn my_app:app
```

How can I design/configure this to support N concurrent users? Let's say, for example, I want to make sure my application can support 100 different users all requesting to download an image at the same time. With several moving parts, I am unsure how to even go about doing this.

Also, if someone requests a download but then loses internet connection before their download is complete, would this cause some sort of lock that could endlessly stall, or would that thread/process automatically timeout after a short period and therefore be handled smoothly?

I currently have 1 dyno (on the Heroku free plan). I am willing to add more dynos if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Run multiple Gunicorn workers](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn#basic-configuration):

> Gunicorn forks multiple system processes within each dyno to allow a Python app to support multiple concurrent requests without requiring them to be thread-safe. In Gunicorn terminology, these are referred to as worker processes (not to be confused with Heroku worker processes, which run in their own dynos).
>
> …
>
> We recommend setting a configuration variable for this setting. Gunicorn automatically honors the `WEB_CONCURRENCY` environment variable, if set.
>
> ```
> heroku config:set WEB_CONCURRENCY=3
> ```

Note that Heroku sets a default `WEB_CONCURRENCY` for you based on your dyno size. You can probably handle a small number of concurrent requests right now.

However, you're not going to get anywhere close to 100 on a free dyno. This section appears between the previous two in the documentation:

> Each forked system process consumes additional memory. This limits how many processes you can run in a single dyno. With a typical Django application memory footprint, you can expect to run 2–4 Gunicorn worker processes on a `free`, `hobby` or `standard-1x` dyno. Your application may allow for a variation of this, depending on your application’s specific memory requirements.

Even if your application is *very* lightweight you probably won't be able to go above 6 workers on a single small dyno. Adding more dynos and / or increasing the number of dynos you run will be required.

Do you *really* need to support 100 concurrent requests? If you have four workers going, four users' requests can be served at the same time. If a fifth makes a request, that request just won't get responded to until one of the workers frees up. That's usually reasonable.

If your request takes an unreasonable amount of time to complete you have a few options besides adding more workers:

- Can you cache the generated images?
- Can you return a response immediately, create the images in a background job, and then notify the user that the images are ready? With some fancy front-end work this can be fairly transparent to the end user.

The right solution will depend on your specific use case. Good luck!